# How to export tuple dataframe to excel as a table

Tags: python, dataframe, tuples

Need your support on below question.

From an excel file i need to find total count in each sheet and put that as a summery new summary sheet and finally export that into mail.

For Example: I have an excel file with 5 pages. I followed following steps

1. read the excel file from local machine [Export the excel file to python]
2. read each sheet and created a dataframe for each sheet
3. counted each rows in all the sheet and printed the result
4. transferred the print result in to data frame again

Now i want to export this data frame to excel with heading and further to a mail using html. Please see the code below.

`sheets = pd.ExcelFile('C:\xxxx\xxxxx\Output\CZ.xlsx')`
`df1 = pd.read_excel(sheets, 'abc')`
`df2 = pd.read_excel(sheets, 'abcd')`
`df3 = pd.read_excel(sheets, 'abcde')`

## Checking Number of entries in each sheet and printing the result

`rows1 = len(df1.axes[0])`
`print("Page 1: ", rows1)`
`rows2 = len(df2.axes[0])`
`print("Page 2: ", rows2)`
`rows3 = len(df3.axes[0])`
`print("Page3: ", rows3)`

Ans

Page 1: 25
Page2: 35
Page3: 45

############################################################

## Putting Print result in to a dataframe

`df4=("Page1",rows1)`
`df5=("Page2",rows2)`
`df6=("Page3",rows3)`

###############################

i need to copy all the above df to one excel sheet like a table  like below

Heading   Total Count
Page1       25
Page2       35
Page 3      45

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
df_list = [df1, df2, ... dfn]

df_combined = df_list[0]
for df in df_list[1:]: 
    df_combined.append(df)
```

```
`
```